# Ubuntu on A1181 (Black Macbook 2,1) by installing on external drive first? (32 bit EFI)

Tags: uefi, macbook, 32-bit

I have seen this question asked before but no solution has worked for me.
I tried flashing Ubuntu 24.04 on a flashdrive via balena. I see the image in there.
I added a 32 bit boot loader as well into the correct folder.
However noth

I also [burned it on a dvd](https://streamable.com/zr15jt) but it would not recognize/boot the disc due to my laptop being the A1181

Question

1. Is it possible to use my modern M1 Mabook air, format/attach external hard disk via usb-c, and install ubuntu directly onto the external drive?
   AND THEN add the 32 bit bootloader and physically install that drive into my a1181 to make this work?

I previously installed 18.04 but wanted to update my hard drive so started with a fresh SSD.

Any and all input is greatly appreciated

Comment: Ubuntu 24.04 (*noble*) doesn't yet exist; it's currently the *development* release Ubuntu *noble* and remains that until it reaches RC state which isn't expected until after 18 April 2024, and isn't on-topic here until release on 25 April 2024.  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/noble-numbat-release-schedule/35649  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.  For support issues with Ubuntu *noble* you'll need to use a #ubuntu-next or #ubuntu+1 site (IRC, UF etc)

Comment: The only two Ubuntu releases you mention are off-topic, ie. 24.04 doesn't yet exist (currently it's Ubuntu *noble* still being an *alpha* release) and Ubuntu 18.04 LTS that is EOSS or EOL depending on architecture (all 32-bit architectures now being EOL).  Have you tried a *supported* Ubuntu product/release?